# QtWebKit QWebView & the Data-URI Protocol - Not supported?

Tags: qtwebkit

We are loading simple HTML in a QWebView, and every image that uses the data-uri protocol does not work.  Instead we see the default placeholder image.  We are using the Arora browser for testing which uses QTWebKit, but also have tested by loading a QWebView through a cpp file.

**Some research I did:**

- According to this source, the Arora browser does not support the data-uri protocol - (and therefore neither QTWebKit?) :
  http://web-browsers.findthebest.com/q/14/2604/What-protocol-support-features-does-the-web-browser-Arora-made-by-Benjamin-C-Meyer-have
- The following comparison article for data-uri support DOES NOT explicitly list Arora or QTWebkit as having support for data-uri:
  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Web_browser_support
- On the following reference page, QT apparently has support for data url stylesheets, but there is nothing explicitly calling out images - and perhaps this is in the c++ code only:
  http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qtwebkit/qwebsettings.html
- Also here, on the webkit list of supported standards, they don't list the data-uri protocol:
  http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/QtWebKitSupportedStandards

In other web references, people make mention of using data-uri images, but in every case they are talking about in the c++ code.  I have not seen a reference to the data-uri protocol working in a QWebView - which is what we need.

**Here is an example of an image we are trying to load:**

```
<img src="data:image/png;charset=utf-8;base64,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">
```

Initially I was loading without the charset, which doesn't make a difference in Chrome.  These images load fine in chrome btw.

So to be clear, I am trying to find out if a QtWebKit QWebView supports the data-uri protocol.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: any news about it? It doesn't work with PhantomJS that relies on QtWebkit, so this seems to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

I got into the same trouble as you with the data-uri images not working in my qt 4.8 app. Going back and forth I discovered I wasn't loading the gif and jpeg plugins. Once I added them to the application path the data-uri's started working.

for OS X this is the solution that works for me:

1. build the app (i use qmake -spec macx-g+++; make clean; make)
2. use qmake -query to find the plugins directory
3. copy imageformats dir into AppName.app/Contents/PlugIns
4. run macdeployqt (to make sure the plugins are pointing to AppName.app/Contents/Frameworks)

done.

p.s. my app wouldn't start with all imageformat libs in the path so i just got the gif and jpeg libs and didn't investigate further

p.p.s you don't need plugin for png images